# Solution design for ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework database first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-access

I’ve inherited an ASP.NET (4.6.1) MVC solution that uses Entity Framework (database first) as its data access. All of the `dbcontext` calls and all of the business logic is in the controller methods. There are no domain models.... only view models and the generated entity models from EF.

So the solution structure is basically:

- Web (MVC web proj) → DAL (EF6...class lib proj)
- DAL contains

  - An .edmx
  - dbContext - auto generated
  - Entity models  - auto generated
  - Partial classes for the entity models
  - Partial dbcontext (contains some custom logic)
- MVC

  - Controller
  - Private dbcontext at class level
  - Some simple to complex CRUD dbcontext calls in each method
  - Models
  - Only view models (some with dbcontext calls...oy)
- Views

  - Some views use VMs as their model while others use EF entity models

At the very least, I want to isolate my DAL from my presentation layer and clean up my controllers. I'm not trying to create the perfect app... but I want to make incremental improvements. So my goal this round is to create a logical structure.

So I’m adding another project in between Web and DAL (called Service or whatever) and I'm moving all of the dbcontext calls/logic into that layer. I'm adding another project (called Core) to hold some DTOs, custom exceptions, and other goodies.

So this is my current solution:

- Web (MVC web proj with Autofac)

  - Some service manager classes (injected into controllers)
  - This is where I get my DTOs and convert them into view models or convert view models into DTOs to send to the Service layer
- Core (not to be confused with .NET Core)

  - Referenced by all
  - Entity models (moved from DAL)
  - Partial classes for the entity models (moved from DAL)
  - DTOs, exceptions, etc...
- Service

  - Referenced by Web
  - Some service classes (injected into Web service managers) that will hold all of the complex CRUD dbcontext calls previously in controller methods (ex: `var result = dbcontext.SomeTable where some id = n...blah blah`)
  - I'll also inject the DAL dbcontext into these classes (which then requires a reference to Entity Framework)
- DAL

  - Referenced by Service
  - An .edmx
  - Dbcontext
  - Partial dbcontext (contains some custom logic)

So I'm keeping the auto generated dbcontext in the DAL, moving the generated entity objects to Core so Service can see them.

My questions:

1. Does it make sense to move all of the dbcontext calls/logic out of the controllers and into the Service? Some of the logic is simple but there are several controller methods that have complex business logic in them as well. I'm just not sure where to put this logic/calls to dbcontext.
2. Does the overall solution design seem OK or am I making it to complex? It's a medium size app but it has potential to grow and I want to set myself up for future development.

Thanks for reading...any input is appreciated!

Comment: It depends on how much time you have to work on the project. I have found that many times you will inherit crummy projects and cleaning them up is always necessary IMHO, but you have to keep in mind that "if it isn't broke dont fix it" mentality because youre a programmer but the end-user doesnt care. Yes, you will be better able to manage the project in the future but at what cost? Is your boss a guy that likes results fast or does he/she appreciate quality control? As far as reliability and speed? It probably wont improve performance.

Comment: I suggest steering away from re-design unless you are implementing something new and more new implementation will be to come and the chnges you make now will make it easier/faster for the future. Alot of programmers don't read up on new technology and only go by with what their experience has brought. Only looking up references to APIs/framework when they have hit a hurdle. Just food for thought.

Comment: I like the use of dependency injection and would create repositories if possible, but then again..meh. Use your best judgement on what and when you should try to improve on this inherited project. Maybe work on an upgrade in your free time and simply follow protocol to the current design at work/on the clock.

Comment: Thanks for your input :) There is new functionality I need to implement which is the only reason I'm considering the restructuring. I don't typically work with an Entity Framework database first structure so I'm just a little puzzled on where the actual dbcontext calls should sit. And the debate over EF and repositories/UoW is just confusing the matter for me :)

Comment: The other comments sum it up - you're refactoring legacy code and need to ask your self if there's business value in doing this. Your changes could introduce a whole load of bugs without you realising. Working effectively with legacy projects is tricky. Refactors like this are pointless if no one outside of business and inside of the business cares. I recommend a plurasight video by Vladimir Khorikov on the subject that's worth watching.